# How can I more accurately report Pytest Selenium passes and failures to SauceLabs?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures, saucelabs

Trying to find the most elegant way to inform the test fixture of a test failure.  This test fixture needs to report the results of the test to saucelabs in order to mark it as pass or fail.  I've tried to delete as much irrelevant code from these examples as possible.

The following test uses the fixture *browser*.

```
def test_9(browser):
    browser.get(MY_CONSTANT)
    assert "My Page" in browser.title
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div > img.THX_IP')
    browser.find_element_by_link_text('Some text').click()
    ... etc
```

The fixture *browser*, which currently is hard coded to mark the test as passed:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):

    driver_type = request.config.getoption('driver')

    if driver_type == 'sauce':
        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor = 'MY_CREDENTIALS',
            desired_capabilities = caps)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    yield driver
    if driver_type == 'sauce':
        sauce_client.jobs.update_job(driver.session_id, passed = True)
    driver.quit()
```

I've discovered a few workarounds but I'd really like to know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following fixture in my conftest.py file which handles all of the pass/fail reporting to sauce. I am not sure if it's "the best way to do it" but it certainly works for us at the moment. We include this fixture for every test that we write.

There's considerably more to this fixture but this section contained at the bottom handles the report really well.

```
def quit():
    try:
        if config.host == "saucelabs":
            if request.node.result_call.failed:
                driver_.execute_script("sauce:job-result=failed")
            elif request.node.result_call.passed:
                driver_.execute_script("sauce:job-result=passed")
    finally:
        driver_.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping to try this today

Comment: I think I'm missing something. AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'result_call'

Comment: There are additional functions that you're going to have to create. We have a driver function which contains the saucelabs details for "remote" tests as well which you might be missing. Wrap the above code in a function (name it whatever). I made an edit to include our function name.